# LINQ subselect in table with composite key

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a settings table in a database that is accessed through Entity Framework queries.
The settings have a composite key: Category, Group, Name, Target, Modified.
The settings obviously also contain non-key fields like value.

How would I write a query that gives me the latest setting within the same (Category, Group, Name, Target)?

More specific, I want all the latest setting entities, including the non-key fields, that matches a specific category, group, target combination.

For example: Give me all the latest settings for all targets where Category is "Database" and Group is "Timeout".

This could be done in two-steps with an initial query returning all [Category, Group, Name, Target, Modified] keys matching the criteria and then a loop querying a setting for each key, but that would produce a lot of database queries, creating overhead.

How would I do this with LINQ if I want to minimize the number of SQL database queries executed by the framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var query = from s in db.Settings
            group s by new
            {
              s.Category,
              s.Group,
              s.Name,
              s.Target,
            } into sg
            select new
            {
              Setting = sg.OrderByDescending(r => r.Modified).FirstOrDefault()
            };
```

Edit - If you want to return a List of Settings

```
 List<Setting> list = (from s in db.Settings
                       group s by new
                       {
                         s.Category,
                         s.Group,
                         s.Name,
                         s.Target,
                       } into sg
                       select sg.OrderByDescending(r => r.Modified).FirstOrDefault()
                      ).ToList();
```

Comment: As far as I can see, this will only return a list of the key-fields of the setting. I need the full setting entity (including such non-key fields as value, description, permissions, etc.), not just the composite key. I am sorry if my question was unclear about that.

Comment: I have modified my question to make it more clear what I want.

Comment: @Holstebroe - My answer returns the whole Settings Entity

Comment: I thought I didn't get the whole setting entity because I used an sb.Settings.Include("Description") to load an associated Description entity. The include doesn't seem to work with the group query.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following LINQ Statement.

```
        List<Settings> latestSettings = 
            db.Settings.OrderByDescending(x => x.Modified).GroupBy(x => new {x.Category, x.Group, x.Name, x.Target}, x => x)
            .Select(result => result.FirstOrDefault())
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi, this only gives me the setting keys. This is a good start, but I also need the rest of the fields in the settings entity.

Comment: Hi Holstebroe, please try it by your own. The result is not only the compound keys, but also the other non key values.

Comment: In my experience with L2E, OrderBy gets ignored if it is before a GroupBy

Comment: @aducci: You might be correct, I would have to retry. But either my or your sql should definitly work.

Comment: You are also right, your query returns the whole setting. Thanks.